# How to convert Binding Expression left and right to lower?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using below code to generate dynamic binding expression; here how to convert expression left and right part to lower? because I wanted to filter either lower case and upper case filter.

```
private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

        switch (filter.Operation)
        {
            case Op.Equals:
                return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

            case Op.GreaterThan:
                return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

            case Op.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.LessThan:
                return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

            case Op.LessThanOrEqual:
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

            case Op.Contains:
                return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);

            case Op.StartsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);

            case Op.EndsWith:
                return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: will using `.ToString().ToLower()` do?

Comment: @Alex It will get error cannot convert string to Expression

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make lowercase?

Comment: the constant and the property types are string ?

Comment: "PropertyName" : 'NationalityName',
 "Operation" : 'Equals',
 "Value" : 'Calicut'

Comment: Above values are passing as list and building a where condition. x=>x.NationalityName=Value. now getting like this. I need to change to x=>x.Nationality.toLower()=Value.toLower()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understand you correctly then you can use the following:

```
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

Expression left = Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
Expression right = Expression.Call(constant, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
```

In your switch replace `member` with `left` and `constant` with `right`

**Update Regarding null checking**
You can check if the member property is null by this: (let's say that `originalExpression` holds the expression from the `switch`)

```
var nullCheck = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(null, member.Type));
```

<del>`Expression.IfThenElse(nullCheck, Expression.Constant(false), originalExpression);`</del>

```
Expression.Conditional(nullCheck, Expression.Constant(false), originalExpression);
```

**Update 2**
You should check for null values both on the property and on the value:

```
var nullCheckProp = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(null, member.Type)); 
var nullCheckVal = Expression.Equal(constant, Expression.Constant(null, constant.Type)); 
var nullCheckBoth = Expression.OrElse(nullCheckProp,nullCheckVal);

Expression.Conditional(nullCheckBoth, Expression.Constant(false), originalExpression);
```

Comment: If I am using multiple Expression for filter; and if any column value is null in table then Iam getting object reference not instance error

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the null check of the property

Comment: not in member property. For example if iam searching ProductName.Contains('AU') and ProductCode=='31'. In this case table have values contains 'AU' and the related ProductCode is 'NULL' then it gives the error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I gave an example of how to check for null. You should adapt it to your case.

Comment: Everything is working proper with your first code. but In database if any 'NULL'  value then I am getting error. in table two rows for ProductName and ProductCode. ie ProductName -> 'AU001', 'AU002' ; ProductCode -> 13, 'NULL'. ProductCode is 'NULL' in second product. I am using expression like ProductName.Contains('AU') and ProductCode=='31'. In this case I am getting error. If I change 'NULL' value to '0' in database then working proper.

Comment: Have you tried what i've added with the null checking? it should solve this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138104/discussion-between-pradees-and-ofir-winegarten).